# create entity framework superclass for different datasources

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 datasources with same Model stucture (just different connection string).
I want to create an entity framework for each. 
Also i want to create a superclass , and then using a parameters in its constructor it will create the correct entity set.
for example,
I have A,B,C datasources.
And a superclass class which will return me an instance of the correct EntityModel (according a parameters in the constructor - for example, an ENUM which represents the chosen DataSource)
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base Class and a Public Property in It e.g

```
public Class ConnectionBase
{  
  public string ConnectionString{ get; private set;}

  public ConnectionBase(Enum connection)
  {
    Switch(connection)

    Case //your value:
     ConnectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your Connection String        from Web Config"]   

   and so on.....

  }


}
```